# Size reduction in ffmpeg conversion of .vob or .mkv to .mp4 or .m4v

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am not an expert in video, but know how to use the Unix command line. I have recently been converting individual movie files from DVD-type formats (.vob or .mkv) to simpler formats for distribution (.mp4) or convenient playback from iTunes (.m4v).

To do this I have been using ffmpeg, with the following type of command on the Mac/Unix command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.VOB -q:v 0 output.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -q:v 0 output.m4v
```

I typically get a reduction to about one fifth of the size in the first case, or, in a recent conversion, one seventh of the size in the second case. As far as I can see there is no reduction in quality (and the subtitles come over ok), so I suppose I should be happy, but perhaps I am not seeing everything.

Can anyone tell me what is being removed and whether it would be better/possible to run ffmpeg in a different way to prevent loss of something important?

**Note**

These conversions are entirely legal. The vob conversions are for a friend who produced a series of commercial craft DVDs some years ago, but needs to sell them on thumb drives. The mkv conversion is for a subtitled movie I purchased as a download.

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011346/ffmpeg-quality-conversion-options-video-compression), `-q:v 0` is probably being ignored. What is the ratio when you try: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv output.mkv`?

Comment: @Rotem — Both the command you suggested, and a variant with output.m4v, give a similar compression to my original. I started with a feature film of 4.13 Gb. My compression with -q:v 0 gave a m4v file of 567.3 Mb, leaving out the qualifiier  gave a m4v file of 567.1 Mb, and doing exactly as you suggested, gave a mkv file of 542.5 Mb. So yes it's being ignored, but what is happening exactly?

Comment: Do some research, and learn the difference between video/audio codec, and media file container. MP4, MKV, M4V and VOB are containers. You may set the codec specifically: `ffmpeg -i input.VOB -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac output.mp4` (for H.264 video codec and AAC audio codec). These are the default codecs that FFmpeg assign to MP4. For MKV the default video codec is H.264, and the default audio codec may be different. Instead of `-q:v`, use `-crf` for selecting the video quality (lower crf applies higher quality). Example for H.265 codec: `ffmpeg -i input.VOB -vcodec libx265 -crf 24 output.mp4`.

Comment: @Rotem — Thanks. That gives me a focus for experimentation and researching terms. But basically it's a question of compression so that it would not be wrong to accept davidgo's answer?

Comment: Accept davidgo's answer. As davidgo
commented "at the level of the question, the answer is appropriate". You are not going to get any better answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VOB files are an older format found on DVDs - I believe that they are either mp2 or close to it - the point being that the compression is relatively light and crude so cheap devices of 20 years ago could decode them in real time.

MP4 compression is much tighter but is now easily done, with much of the logic to do so baked into most CPUs.

There is likely a theoretical loss of quality (mp4 is lossy), but it’s not hard to convert an mp2 to mp4 with a dramatic size decrease but no perceivable loss in output quality.

Comment: Thanks. I see you are correct, but I'll find some links to add to this comment (or your answer if you don't mind) where this is documented. (Unless you would like to add them.)

Comment: MP4 is a container format. The more relevant property is the video codec.

Comment: @Rotem Quite so, but mp4 specifies a number of codecs, almost all with much greater compression then the VOB mp2 format.  At the level of the question, I believe my answer is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've corrected a couple of typos I noticed.